# Less return statements in assembly than in source code

Tags: ida

So I was doing some reversing on a binary I created to learn assembly and I came across a subroutine that had fewer return statements than I had in my original source code. The .text section has 2 return statements, the decompiled c-source code has 3 return statements but my original source code has 4 return statements.
I'm using 64-bit IDA 7.0 pro, my file is also 64-bit. I'm trying to figure out why this is.

IDA .TEXT VIEW: https://gyazo.com/00fc89ed15dfe8485df620f89185bbdf

IDA DECOMPILED C-SOURCE VIEW: https://gyazo.com/b78e153a50716e1804d08921438f4289

ORIGINAL SOURCE CODE: https://gyazo.com/e0071904abc06c51958af009e23808ae

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code.

Comment: You could have even one return in assembly, because all of you returns does the same: calls `CallNextHookEx` with params.The code prepares everything for a proper function call and then calls the function.